# adb devices isn't working on Mountain Lion

Tags: android, adb, osx-mountain-lion, nexus-one

I just upgraded to OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion).  Now adb devices doesn't list my Galaxy Nexus or my Nexus One.  I can't believe it isn't working as I'm sure there must be Android devs at Google that use Google phones with Mountain Lion.  Please help!

Comment: I think you need to reinstall/configure the drivers.

Comment: I too upgraded to Mountain Lion, but did not experience any problems with my Galaxy Nexus. adb is sometimes flaky, regardless of desktop OS. Try (1) add kill-server and (2) a different cable.

Comment: try adb kill-server followed by adb start-server

Comment: then adb devices.  If this does not work, and not cable then its the drivers Collins.

Comment: Also see if other devices are recognized.

Comment: @ligi sorry for asking hard questions :-P

Comment: @CodeDroid I never had to install any drivers in the first place.  It "just worked" before.

Comment: @YusufX I've been using the same cable and devices with Lion for months without issue.  Seems strange that it suddenly stopped working when I upgraded.  Perhaps I damaged my cable but I doubt it.

Comment: @YusufX Also, the cable doesn't have any issues charging the device

Comment: @richcollins I have noticed the exact same issue with all my many devices as soon as I upgraded.  I've posted in the Google Group to try and get a resolution from the Googlers: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/8BNsMuuZCFc%5B1-25%5D

Comment: In the interim, the best way to get them to detect quickly is to reboot the device while its connected to the machine.

Comment: Mountain Lion / Sony Xperia Ray working here well. Sometimes I need to unplug/plug but apart from that no issues.

Answer (score 2):

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Me and my team was also seeing similar issues with mountain lion, but the issues mainly because of ADB not working properly. As described in comments

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

is your best friend. Always worked for us. However please note that you may have to do it multiple times, meaning it hangs do it again. Infact, the automated test script that we have written goes to an extent of executing these commands, the moment it feels we are not getting response.